# Object.fromEntries () is not respecting the order of the iterator

Tags: javascript

I need to sort the following object by its keys

```
const leagues = {
  2020: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}],
  2021: [{}],
  2022: [{}],
};
```

To this end try the following

```
const entries = Object.entries(leagues).sort((a, b) => b[0].localeCompare(a[0]));
```

I get the expected result

```
[
  [ '2022', [ {} ] ],
  [ '2021', [ {} ] ],
  [
    '2020',
    [
      {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
      {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
      {}
    ]
  ]
]
```

Now I want to transform this result into an object again, for this I try the following

```
const output = Object.fromEntries(entries);
```

Curiously the output of this call forgets the order

```
{
  '2020': [
    {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
    {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
    {}
  ],
  '2021': [ {} ],
  '2022': [ {} ]
}
```

How can I achieve the expected result?

Comment: Array-indexed keys are always iterated over in ascending order. Use something else, like a Map or array of objects, to preserve insertion order

Comment: thanks for answering, could you share an example to guide me

Comment: Like I said, use a Map or array instead of an object to organize the data